# Using jquery to make a photo slide show

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm currently trying to create a basic image slide show and am having some issues. The images change abruptly and then fade back to the first image. Then after they fully cycle through the photos it works as it should and simply fades between images. I have been playing around with this for the last couple hours and I'm not sure where to go from here. All I want the images to do is fade into a slideshow.

Here's a fiddle link
jsfiddle.net/7knnb92s

Script

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  2000);
```

HTML

```
<center>
<div id="slideshow" class="Photos">
<div>
<img src="Image1.jpg" alt = "Image1" width="1000" height="600">
</div>
<div>
<img src="Image2.jpg" alt = "Image2" width="1000" height="600">
</div>
<div>
<img src="Image3.jpg" alt = "Image3" width="1000" height="600">
</div>
<div>
<img src="Image4.jpg" alt = "Image4" width="1000" height="600">
</div>
</center>
```

CSS

```
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: center; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 55px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle with the problem, please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7knnb92s/ I just replaced the image files with images I have online but now it won't cycle at all.

Comment: Seems to work fine. You forgot to request jQuery on the environment. JSFiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/7knnb92s/1/

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle out. it works flawlessly.`enter code here`

```js
var i = 0;
var num = $('#slideshow div').length-1;
$('#slideshow div:eq('+i+')').fadeIn('fast');
setInterval(function () {
    $('#slideshow div:eq('+i+')').fadeOut(1000);
    i = i<num?i+1:0;
     $('#slideshow div:eq('+i+')').fadeIn(1000);
}, 3000);
```

```css
#slideshow {
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: center;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#slideshow > div {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<center>
    <div id="slideshow" class="Photos">
        <div>
            <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/1422563_738192282896557_6327050085052054804_n.jpg?oh=ed991fb626a0a2cff6e19cb48955d064&oe=54E2A201&__gda__=1427388096_818ee4b1966fb5ec7f43d51bf02f0b33" alt="Image1" width="1000" height="600">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://scontent-b-atl.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10383629_738202862895499_6804583242811023005_n.jpg?oh=ed4f54107f44ec1fc588f3659ee3d6a2&oe=55141903" alt="Image2" width="1000" height="600">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://scontent-b-atl.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10429225_738197656229353_8756451198102185139_n.jpg?oh=0ef2e3c331300ba3c6dd1194c40d8400&oe=54D5C076" alt="Image3" width="1000" height="600">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/10374994_738202209562231_9201950715066845451_n.jpg?oh=0aaad6132a69d47f75d33eb758605054&oe=54D5E109&__gda__=1427247167_560dc112c3b9ae2cd0c158a3f91556cf" alt="Image4" width="1000" height="600">
        </div>
</div>
</center>
```